# Open VPN connection doesnt work after reboot Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vpn, connection, reboot, openvpn

First I like to thank anyone who is giving these great answer here ! Im a new Ubuntu user and still on learning curve. After 8 years of OSX it is been harder than I expected. Two weeks ago I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Samsung ATIV Book 9 Lite. I had hard time with BIOS and get machine boot from USB and finally boot to Ubuntu. Thats why I found this website and found fix to it.

I think my machine is pretty much ready to go. I have followed lots of videos and articles such as "top 5/10 things to do after installing Ubuntu". So I have done all updates and tweaks through command line.

I have premium plus account for CyberGhost VPN service so I wanted to install OpenVPN to my new fresh Linux machine. I found these excellent tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-qLZmp5WBo

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
sudo apt-get install openvpn bridge-utils
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
sudo restart network-manager
```

for my big suprice my VPN was working after first attemp ! Big thank you again to Scott Hunt. VPN was working flawlessly but after reboot clicking task bar network -- VPN connections -- (name of my VPN) nothing happened. Wirelesss indicator was not even trying to connect.I tried another reboot and checked setting but all was as they should be. Its not connecting. I dont know how to check any error logs etc. even if do, it wont help me much...

I though something went wrong during installation so I thought I could do fresh install of OS and update everything just to practice and get more comfortable with Ubuntu. When everything was back to square one I started install VPN again.

This time following previous link from youtube and cyberghost own install guide https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/395/0/configure-openvpn-for-linux-mint

Like said my first attemp was using OpenVPN UDP .ovpn with you youtube provide settings and it worked fine until reboot.

After fresh OS installation i made VPN with TCP .ovnp and provide setting from cyberghost link. And for my bit suprice new TCP vpn connection work after clicking it !! All was fine like after first vpn installation but... after reboot it wont connect again. After two weeks with Ubuntu experience I have no tools to troubleshoot this. Hours of searching answers from forums im more confused. I have no other option to post my question and hope someone would find time to write step by step instruction get this thing work and hopefully someone who has same problem founds it too.

ok, i dont know what im doing here but i was able to find a command how to look log files. I dont know if these are any usefull because i dont understand or can read it. Maybe this is some help for someone ?

```
cyberghost@CyberGhost:~$ grep VPN /var/log/syslog
Feb 11 01:57:16 CyberGhost NetworkManager[737]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Feb 11 01:57:16 CyberGhost NetworkManager[737]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 3791
Feb 11 01:57:16 CyberGhost NetworkManager[737]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Feb 11 01:57:16 CyberGhost NetworkManager[737]: <error> [1423612636.123729] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1374] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Feb 11 01:57:21 CyberGhost NetworkManager[737]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
Feb 11 10:51:24 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
Feb 11 10:51:24 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn
Feb 11 10:51:40 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Feb 11 10:51:40 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 5487
Feb 11 10:51:40 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Feb 11 10:51:40 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <error> [1423644700.329580] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1374] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Feb 11 10:51:45 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
Feb 11 21:12:54 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Feb 11 21:12:54 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 7569
Feb 11 21:12:54 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Feb 11 21:12:54 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <error> [1423681974.194144] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1374] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Feb 11 21:12:59 CyberGhost NetworkManager[5339]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
Feb 11 21:15:58 CyberGhost NetworkManager[767]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
Feb 11 21:15:58 CyberGhost NetworkManager[767]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn
Feb 11 22:21:35 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
Feb 11 22:21:35 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn
Feb 11 22:27:10 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Feb 11 22:27:10 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 2986
Feb 11 22:27:10 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Feb 11 22:27:10 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <error> [1423686430.334729] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1374] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Feb 11 22:27:15 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
Feb 11 22:27:18 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Feb 11 22:27:18 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 2989
Feb 11 22:27:18 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Feb 11 22:27:18 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <error> [1423686438.614084] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1374] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Feb 11 22:27:23 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
Feb 11 22:27:24 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Feb 11 22:27:24 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 2992
Feb 11 22:27:24 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Feb 11 22:27:24 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <error> [1423686444.783814] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1374] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Feb 11 22:27:29 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
Feb 11 22:27:30 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Feb 11 22:27:30 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 2995
Feb 11 22:27:30 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Feb 11 22:27:30 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <error> [1423686450.537733] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1374] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Feb 11 22:27:35 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
Feb 11 23:10:18 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Feb 11 23:10:18 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 3431
Feb 11 23:10:18 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Feb 11 23:10:18 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <error> [1423689018.394501] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1374] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Feb 11 23:10:23 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
Feb 11 23:18:21 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Feb 11 23:18:21 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 3613
Feb 11 23:18:21 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Feb 11 23:18:21 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <error> [1423689501.604361] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1374] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Feb 11 23:18:26 CyberGhost NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
cyberghost@CyberGhost:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a nugget of knowledge: OSX for MAC is based off Darwin, which is a distribution of Linux. So the commands and the like are similar to each other. Try that way of thinking to see if you can refine your approach to your problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this error although I encountered it after a week of OpenVPN usage, including multiple power downs and reboots. I found an obscure idea to restart the dbus service in Ubuntu.

```
sudo service dbus restart
```

It might be wise to concat with another command to restart your GUI since a power button reboot was necessary for me after I executed this command. But afterwards I was able to connect to my VPN as normal.